# Find the initial term and the common difference of all APs such that, if a number $k$ is a term in the progression, so is $k^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have found out that if initial term = common difference, both of them being natural numbers, any arbitrary $k$ in the progression is a multiple of $a$, and by that virtue, so is $k^2$.
Ex: $$(ak)^2 = a^2 \cdot k^2 = a(ak^2)$$
I am unable to rigorously proof this result, and would like to know if there is an analytical method which  I can utilize.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs. `$k^2$` gives $k^2$

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand your question. It would help if you gave some background into what you are asking about, rather than launching into 'if initial term=common difference...'.

Comment: I suppose I did frame the question a bit obtuse. Ex: Take the AP: 3, 6, 9, 12...
The square of the first term is in the AP. Take the second term, 6, and we find that 36 (6^2) is also in the AP and so on. I want to find the initial term and the common difference of all APs such as the example I've given.